# apache - Require HTTP basic auth on ScriptAlias Location

Tags: apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I have a `ScriptAlias` configured like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ScriptAlias /path/ "/path/to/bin/cgi"
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to use Apache to put a basic auth wall in front of this. My first instinct is to try

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Location "/path">
        ScriptAlias / "/path/to/bin/cgi"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName ...
        ... other auth stuff ...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try this, I get this error

```
ScriptAlias cannot occur within directory context
```

How do I put basic auth in front of this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I did not try this, which worked:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ScriptAlias /path "/path/to/bin/cgi"
    <Location "/path">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName ...
        ... other auth stuff ...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```